# Google Map get Freeze if lock and unlock device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been implemented google Map service in my one of the Android App, the map is loaded when, 'user get signIn and go to home page' and at home page we have some Tabs to navigate. the problem is that, when i came on Homepage the map loaded properly and zoom In,zoom out to also if i navigate through tabs and come back on home map functionality work well. but when I am in Home page and press Lock key and after unlocking check my home page the Map Freeze not zoomIn not Zoom out. while ones i navigate to another tab and come back on home it perform well again.

Please allow me solution for Freezing Google Map on Lock Press
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you checked if your Android app used enough of RAM which your device can handle? It could be related to clearing the cache as discussed in this [thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102803/why-are-google-maps-9-5-1-running-slow-freezing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking lots off i found mistake. In a onPause() method the fragment get removed. like "getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapHomeFrag).commit()"
So if i lock the device my HomeFragment goes to OnPause() and remove my transaction and map got Freeze. While when i am navigating through Tab the fragment reload so no issue happen.